# iOS warning about an enumeration

Tags: ios, for-loop, nsstring, nsarray, enumeration

```
NSString *arrayOfStrings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://", @"https://", nil];
NSString *stringToSearchWithin = webpageURLLabel.text;

BOOL found=NO;
for (NSString *s in arrayOfStrings)
```

The for loop says

> Collection expression type 'NSString *' may not respond to
>   'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:'

how do I fix it? Right now its only a warning but I would rather not see any warnings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are declaring arrayOfStrings as a NSString. it should be NSArray